# issues installing libjpeg for mac (macports)

Tags: jpeg, macports, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo, torch

I use a macbook (with Yosemite). I am quite new to macports.

However, i need to install libjpeg (so i can use torch7 fully), but get this error When i try:

```
sudo port install libjpeg-turbo
```

result:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for libjpeg-turbo
Error: Unable to execute port: Can't install libjpeg-turbo because
conflicting ports are active: jpeg
```

I dont know quite what to do? as i don't think i can uninstall jpeg without problems

Answer (score 3):

You can deactivate the conflicting port first with:

```
sudo port -f deactivate jpeg
sudo port install libjpeg-turbo
```